# How to post array values via curl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, rest, post, curl

I like to test an API backend which is designed as shown in the following example:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/shops/1.json
```

The JSON response:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Supermarket",
  products: [
    "fruit",
    "eggs"
  ]
}
```

Here is the corresponding model:

```
# app/models/shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Enumerize
  attr_accessible :name, :products

  serialize :products, Array
  enumerize :products, in: %w{fruit meat eggs}, multiple: true

  resourcify

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { in: 5..50 }    
  validates :products, presence: true
end
```

I want to use *curl* to test creating and updating a entry. Therefore, I use the following commands:

Create:

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/shops.json -d \
  "shop[name]=Supermarket&shop[products]=fruit,eggs&auth_token=a1b2c3d4"
```

Update:

```
$ curl -X PUT http://localhost:3000/api/v1/shops/1.json -d \
  "shop[name]=Supermarket&&shop[products]=fruit,eggs&auth_token=a1b2c3d4"
```

The value for `products` need to be submitted as an array. When I run the above commands the following message is returned:

```
{"errors":{"products":["is invalid"]}
```

How do I need to write the values of the `products` array so it works with *curl*?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/shops.json -d \
  "shop[name]=Supermarket \
  &shop[products][]=fruit \
  &shop[products][]=eggs \
  &auth_token=a1b2c3d4"
```

Comment: What if I have an existing array I want to add to? Would this clear the product array and replace it with these two products?  Or would it append them to the list of existing products?  (I'd like to find a way to do the latter)

Comment: @TomHammond I think you should post this as a separate question, I will gladly answer you!

Comment: Sure thing - here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327098/how-to-update-array-values-with-curl