# Rack + Sinatra + Post Request Parsing

Tags: parsing, sinatra, rack

How can prevent Rack request parser for post request to filter out params with empty array value?

my params consist of something like {'imp_key' => [], 'notified' => 'true'}. However rack parser removed imp_key and I get only notified as params but I want to get all params I have send to it.

Comment: Does it do it with a GET? Have you tested this via a tool like cURL? If you've used a browser to test it, are the params showing properly if you look at the request using its development tools?

Comment: i am not using browser for this simulation, actually its an api call from one of my app to another. I have replicated it from irb as well using HTTParty to do a post request

Comment: Can you post the raw request data so that we can try playing with it? It doesn't have to be real data, just the correct structure. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17107542/335847) for an example of raw cURL requests.

Answer (score -1):

I am running into the same issue and can confirm it is a problem. I've traced it down to [lib/rack/test/utils.rb:19](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/master/Rack/Test/Utils.build_nested_query) in build_nested_query. Any parameters with values of empty arrays are getting stripped there

EDIT: This appears to be an open issue with rack-test. See the [Github issue](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test/issues/122)